# Find non-adjacent repeating values in tuple in PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Is there a way to discard tuples that have repeating non adjacent (not next to each other) values?

Given list of tuples:

```
(1,2,3)

(1,1,2)

(1,2,1)

(2,2,1,2)
```

Want these:

```
(1,2,3)

(1,1,2)
```

Don't want these:

```
(1,2,1)

(2,2,1,2)
```

Comment: was thinking record the index of each value in the tuple. Group by the value. Then calculate if the range of indexes is greater than the size of each values's group.

Comment: interesting! 
came across kind of similar question, the guy ended up writing UDF. You might want to talk to him.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618383/remove-duplicate-contiguous-elements-in-pig