# Remove duplicate contiguous elements in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is there a way to remove duplicate adjacent elements in pig without writing a UDF?

Example tuple:

`[1,2,3,3,3,4,1,1,2]` -> `[1,2,3,4,1,2]`

Comment: giving up, created UDF

Comment: this is very specific requirement. I doubt if there is be any UDF written for this task.